# How can I create a list that spans on two columns on large screens and one column on mobile?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create something like below with flexbox or do I need CSS grid?

I want the list to be on two columns, but when I resize the window to be on one column.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's possible using the two. But please post the code of yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flex-wrap` property to wrap your elements into another when they hit some requirements. Let's say

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
ul li {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

In this case your li-element will be wrapped when there is no 300px-space for him and you can avoid media-queries (1000px available space - there will be three columns, 700px - two columns, etc...)
But in this case your elements will be wrapped line by line like this:

```
 - One - Two
 - Three - Four
 - Five - Six
 - Seven
```

If you want them to be wrapped by the height of it's parent you should restrict height of the parent by `height` or `max-height` (what suits your needs best) and add `flex-direction: column`

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-height: 100px;
}
```

In this case when column hit 100px height it will wrap and we'll see something like this:

```
 - One - Six
 - Two - Seven
 - Three
 - Four
 - Five
```

Unfortunally, I don't see the way to avoid media-queries in this case, so set `max-height: none`

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    ul {
        max-height: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your time.